# Concept of xml files for haar cascade in object detection with opencv?

Tags: object-detection

I've just started ML and since I entered a project on object detection, their haar cascade is used and XML files are loaded via OpenCV for detection. So I would like to understand why XML files are used. Also can I get such files for detection of any other features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML files are generated when you train the Haar Cascade Classifier. From the [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html):

> Object Detection using Haar feature-based cascade classifiers is an effective object detection method proposed by Paul Viola and Michael Jones in their paper, "Rapid Object Detection using a Boosted Cascade of Simple Features" in 2001. It is a machine learning based approach where a cascade function is trained from a lot of positive and negative images. It is then used to detect objects in other images

More information on Haar cascades can be found [here](http://www.willberger.org/cascade-haar-explained/).

Some tutorials for training Haar Cascades are available.

- [Link 1](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html)
- [Link 2](https://medium.com/@dikshitkathuria1803/training-your-own-cascade-classifier-detector-opencv-9ea6055242c2)
- [Link 3](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/)